# Error running chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I get this error when i try to start chromedriver on debian lenny -

./chromedriver: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by ./chromedriver)
./chromedriver: /lib/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by ./chromedriver)
./chromedriver: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by ./chromedriver)

How do i get around this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenny has old libraries which google chrome does not support. So i moved to  debian squeeze which solved my issue.