# chromedriver doesn't run in debian wheezy

Tags: python, selenium, debian, selenium-chromedriver

This question is very similar to [Error running chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929197/error-running-chromedriver), except that question is about older debian versions.

Here is the info about my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux host 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)

$ chromedriver
chromedriver: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by chromedriver)
```

I am sure I got the right 32bit chromedriver binary from http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list, I am also sure it's in PATH, as the command above shows.

How do I get chromedriver to work properly? Is there a working Debian package of chromedriver like there's one for chromium browser in the Debian repository?

Comment: Note: wheezy is a debian build version.

Comment: @CoolBeans: I'm not sure what I am supposed to change

Comment: I apologize. My comment intended for people dropping "wheezy" from your question.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I tried downloading older versions of chromedriver, but they too have been compiled against newer versions of glibc. As of this writing, Wheezy is the latest version. There are newer glibc versions in the Experimental repository, but using those is not an option in my particular case.

Comment: @Nim: No I didn't manage to resolve this, despite even trying to build chromedriver from source myself. I have cut the Gordian Knot by completely giving up on using chromedriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AnonymousLurker: Someone complained about this problem over on the google code page: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=454

Reason I'm mentioning it here, is because someone else on the thread actually got a clean build (32bit Release) for Debian Wheezy, which you can still download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3120756/chromedriver) (as of Nov. 9).

I've got it working on my own personal jenkins server (`Debian GNU/Linux 7.2 (wheezy)` 64bit).

Comment: Thanks, but after getting a lot of white hair while trying to compile the thing myself I gave up, switched to PhantomJS and I'm very happy. I am going to accept your answer since it answers my question. However, depending of a third party package that may stop working once debian gets a new chromium version that may break backwards compatibility is risky.